# Azure App Service Docker Container running Rust App Making Outbound HTTP Request "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: azure, docker, rust, azure-web-app-service

I think the issue must be with my Azure setup. I have an app service that is running a container for a rust web service. That web service needs to make an outbound https request. However, when I try to do that I get this error:

```
"error in reqwest: error sending request for url (https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/######/Messages.json): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919: (unable to get local issuer certificate)"
```

I am using a managed certificate from Azure App Service. Does anyone have a hunch of what the issue might be? Or is familiar with this kind of issue in Azure?

Comment: Looks like it's related to twilio and HTTPS. if you put that in Google, you'll find a cert to download that might help

Comment: Shoot I think you are right. Here's this article I found: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007853433-Troubleshooting-Certificate-Errors-from-the-Twilio-REST-API.

I'm going to try to add `update-ca-certificates` to my Dockerfile and see if that works :)

Comment: Sounds good. I put all the information into an answer that you can accept if everything worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that your docker container does not have current CA certificates installed. Twilio updated their root certificate a while back and this can cause some issues.

Try running `update-ca-certificates` or one of the other [suggested solutions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007853433-Troubleshooting-Certificate-Errors-from-the-Twilio-REST-API).

Comment: This really worked! I added to my Dockerfile:
`RUN apt-get update \n RUN apt-get install ca-certificates -y \n RUN update-ca-certificates`
Thanks!